# Trying to display the Volume of a pyramid in my GUI using tkinter but nothing shows up next to value

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter-entry

I cant seem to get it to display the calculated volume. I tried debugging(hence the print statements) and when I print it shows "PY_VAR0" as the value of self.volume. Trying to use the set method to get the calculated value over to the StringVar()

```
 def pyramid_button(self):
    # create the pyramid window
    self.pyramid_button_window = tkinter.Tk()
    self.pyramid_button_window.geometry('300x300')
    self.pyramid_button_window.title('Pyramid Volume')

    # create frames for secondary windows
    self.length_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.pyramid_button_window)
    self.width_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.pyramid_button_window)
    self.height_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.pyramid_button_window)
    self.volume_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.pyramid_button_window)
    self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.pyramid_button_window)

    # create and pack widgets for pyramid length
    self.length_label = tkinter.Label(self.length_frame, text='Enter the base length of the pyramid:')
    self.length_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.length_frame, width=10)
    self.length_label.pack(side='left')
    self.length_entry.pack(side='left')

    # create and pack widgets for pyramid width
    self.width_label = tkinter.Label(self.width_frame, text='Enter the base  width of the pyramid:')
    self.width_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.width_frame, width=10)
    self.width_label.pack(side='left')
    self.width_entry.pack(side='left')

    # create and pack widgets for pyramid height
    self.height_label = tkinter.Label(self.height_frame, text='Enter the base  width of the pyramid:')
    self.height_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.height_frame, width=10)
    self.height_label.pack(side='left')
    self.height_entry.pack(side='left')

    # create and pack widgets for calculated pyramid volume
    self.volume_label = tkinter.Label(self.volume_frame, text='Volume: ')
    self.volume = tkinter.StringVar()
    self.calculated_volume_label = tkinter.Label(self.volume_frame, textvariable=self.volume)
    self.volume_label.pack(side='left')
    self.calculated_volume_label.pack(side='left')

    # create and pack button widgets
    self.p_calc_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, text='Volume', command=self.calc_p_volume)
    self.p_close_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame, text='Close',
                                         command=self.pyramid_button_window.destroy)
    self.p_calc_button.pack(side='left')
    self.p_close_button.pack(side='left')

    # Pack the frames
    self.length_frame.pack()
    self.width_frame.pack()
    self.height_frame.pack()
    self.volume_frame.pack()
    self.button_frame.pack()

def calc_p_volume(self):
    # get length, width, height and store them
    # in variables

    self.length = float(self.length_entry.get())
    self.width = float(self.width_entry.get())
    self.height = float(self.height_entry.get())
    print(self.height, self.width, self.length)

    # calculate the volume

    self.p_volume = ((self.length * self.width * self.height)/3)
    print(self.p_volume)

    # update the volume label with calculated self.p_volume
    self.volume.set(self.p_volume)
    print(self.volume)
```

I tried to hit the calculate button to get the intended result and it won't display anything. Is it not setting the value to the variable?

Comment: I suspect that your overall program contains multiple calls to `Tk()`, which create entirely independent GUI environments - a StringVar that is set in one environment simply will not have any effect on a widget that lives in a different environment.  Use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows that all live in the same environment.

Comment: You should `print(self.volume.get())`, `get()` is used to retrieve the value off the `StringVar`. Closing this a typo